# How do I exclude an index signature from a type?

Tags: typescript

If I define my types as follows, it follows my desired behavior.

```
interface Foo {}

interface Bar {
    a: string;
    b: boolean;
    c: Foo;
}

type x = keyof Bar; // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

However, if I try to add an index signature, it loses all my predefined members.

```
interface Bar {
    [index: string]: any;
}

type x = keyof Bar; // string | number
```

Is there a way to do this properly in TypeScript?

Something similar to:

```
type x = Exclude<Bar, { [index: string]: any }>; // never
```

---

**EDIT**
I tried something similar to Jake's solution and got this:

```
interface Indexable<T> {
    [index: string]: any;
}
type BaseType<T> = T extends Indexable<infer U> ? U : never;

interface BaseFoo {
    Name: string;
}
interface Foo1 extends Indexable<BaseFoo> {}
type Foo2 = Indexable<BaseFoo>;

type base1 = BaseType<Foo1>; // {}
type base2 = BaseType<Foo2>; // BaseFoo
```

`Foo1` does not work, for some reason the type info for that becomes `{}`.
`Foo2` *does* work, but intellisense does not say `Foo2` for variables of type `Foo2`. They instead have `Indexable<BaseFoo>`.

I would really like to try to hide this type massaging from my users. And unfortunately, it's not feasible to ask them to cast back and forth from `Indexable<T>` to `T`.

Comment: Don't think there is a way to do this. Once you add an index signature to the mix `keyof`will return `string ` so you can't get to the named keys and excluding the index signature is also not possible as any conditional type constraint that has a signature will also match the properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: remove index signature using mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465182/typescript-remove-index-signature-using-mapped-types)

This question is technically older (by 10 days), but the other one has an answer.

Comment: Thanks for linking other thread, it has a real answer! 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Answer

UPDATE: As of TS 4.1 there is a real solution: [How to remove index signature using mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465182/how-to-remove-index-signature-using-mapped-types)

## Alternative

Get the keys *before* adding the index signature:

```
interface Foo {}

interface BarCore {
    a: string;
    b: boolean;
    c: Foo;
}


type Bar = BarCore & {
    [index: string]: any;
}

type X = keyof BarCore; // a|b|c
```

## More

PS: try not to mix index signatures with valid prop at root level. Instead use the [nested object pattern](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#design-pattern-nested-index-signature)

Answer (score 0):

No, because this is the correct behaviour. `string | "x"` will simplify to `string` because `"x" extends string` is true. You get `string | number` when you only defined a `string` index signature because JavaScript casts numeric indices to string indices on objects.

If you want the behavior you're looking for you're going to need to change your interface definitions.

```
interface Foo {}

interface Bar {
    a: string;
    b: boolean;
    c: Foo;
}

interface IndexedBar extends Bar {
    [ key: string ]: any;
}

type x = keyof Bar; // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Also note that you won't get correct type-checking on `IndexedBar` in some cases.

```
function setValue(obj: IndexedBar, key: string, value: any): void {
    obj[key] = value;
}

setValue(bar, "a", 4); // No error, even though a is explicitly a string.
```

Comment: I think this is most of the way to what I want. I updated my question with some more information. Thanks!