# How can I get a union of just the known property keys from a type that has a string index signature?

Tags: typescript

Using the Exclude operator doesn't work.

```
type test = Exclude<'a'|'b'|string, string>
// produces type test = never
```

I can understand why "except strings" also means excluding all the string literals, but how can I obtain `'a'|'b'` out of `'a'|'b'|string`?

If needed, assume latest TypeScript.

The usecase is as follows:

Say a third party library defines this type:

```
export interface JSONSchema4 {
  id?: string
  $ref?: string
  $schema?: string
  title?: string
  description?: string
  default?: JSONSchema4Type
  multipleOf?: number
  maximum?: number
  exclusiveMaximum?: boolean
  minimum?: number
  exclusiveMinimum?: boolean
  maxLength?: number
  minLength?: number
  pattern?: string
  // to allow third party extensions
  [k: string]: any
}
```

Now, what I want to do, is get a union of the KNOWN properties:

```
type KnownProperties = Exclude<keyof JSONSchema4, string|number>
```

Somewhat understandably, this fails and gives an empty type.

If you are reading this but I was hit by a bus, the answer to this might be found in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-414777939).

Comment: `'a'|'b'|string` simplifies to `string` before you can do anything else with it.  You'll have to change whatever code is generating this type.  What is that code?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen that union is the result of `keyof` on an interface. I am editing the question right now.

Comment: The crux of the issue is to remove the index signature.  In a few minutes of messing around, I was unable to find a way to do it.  In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465182/typescript-remove-index-signature-using-mapped-types), jcalz claims it can't be done, and I'd tend to believe him.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I found a way, I added it as an answer.

Comment: That is amazing... someone go to the other thread and answer it or link it here.

Comment: @jcalz I answered it there, I can't accept my answer here and hence do a duplicate link (Is this even a duplicate?) for two more days though. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956054/2115619

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### Current solution (Typescript `4.1`+)

**2021 Edit:** The `2.8` implementation of `KnownKeys<T>` is [broken since Typescript `4.3.1-rc`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44143), but a new, more semantic implementation using *[key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types)* is available since `4.1`:

```
type RemoveIndex<T> = {
  [ K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K ] : T[K]
};
```

It can then be used as follows:

```
type KnownKeys<T> = keyof RemoveIndex<T>;

interface test {
  req: string
  opt?: string
  [k: string]: any
}

type demo = KnownKeys<test>; // "req" | "opt" // Absolutely glorious!
```

#### Below is the preserved solution for pre-`4.1` Typescript versions:

---

I got a solution from [**@ferdaber**](https://github.com/ferdaber) in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-414782407).

**Edit:** Turns out it was, to little fanfare, [published in 1986](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25987#issuecomment-408339599) by [**@ajafff**](https://github.com/ajafff)

The solution requires TypeScript 2.8's [**Conditional Types**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) and goes as follows:

```
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;
```

Below is my attempt at an explaination:

The solution is based on the fact that `string` extends `string` (just as `'a'` extends `string`) but `string` doesn't extend `'a'`, and similarly for numbers.
Basically, we must think of `extends` as "goes into"

First it creates a mapped type, where for every key of T, the value is:

- if string extends key (key is string, not a subtype) => never
- if number extends key (key is number, not a subtype) => never
- else, the actual string key

Then, it does essentially valueof to get a union of all the values:

```
type ValuesOf<T> = T extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never
```

Or, more exactly:

```
interface test {
  req: string
  opt?: string
  [k: string]: any
}
type FirstHalf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
}

type ValuesOf<T> = T extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never
// or equivalently, since T here, and T in FirstHalf have the same keys,
// we can use T from FirstHalf instead:
type SecondHalf<First, T> = First extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;

type a = FirstHalf<test>
//Output:
type a = {
    [x: string]: never;
    req: "req";
    opt?: "opt" | undefined;
}
type a2 = ValuesOf<a> //  "req" | "opt" // Success!
type a2b = SecondHalf<a, test> //  "req" | "opt" // Success!

// Substituting, to create a single type definition, we get @ferdaber's solution:
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;
// type b = KnownKeys<test> //  "req" | "opt" // Absolutely glorious!
```

[Explaination in GitHub thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-414783301) in case someone makes an objection over there

Comment: Wow!  That is very clever.

Comment: The answer is brilliant!! Bout I think the interface test.opt should be optional, since type a is generated from FirstHalf<T> and a.opt has value `undefined`

Comment: Did not work here: ```const keysToSync = ['apitoken', 'userId', 'active-trade-account'] as const;
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;
type KeysToSync = KnownKeys<keyof typeof keysToSync>;
```

Comment: @DevinRhode `KnownKeys` works on keyed collections, not naked unions.
`KnownKeys<typeof keysToSync>` correctly produces `"0" | "1" | "2"`. (Yes, it is unfortunate they are strings and not numbers, but that's the truth of the indexing semantics of JS). Notably, the `KnownKeys` *is* useful here in that it removes the `number | ` from the type.

Answer (score 2):

Per accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955852/714179. In TS 4.3.2 this works:

```
export type KnownKeys<T> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K]: never
}
```

Comment: I didn't include https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956054/2115619 because this question is tagged with `typescript 2.8` and Key Remapping is introduced in Typescript 4.1

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis you probably should edit it in (with a note about versions and a link to [ms/TS#44143](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44143)) just because people will be unlikely to continue consulting this Q/A for TS2.8.

Comment: How did you make that link :o

Comment: @jcalz done, I think