# Exclude dynamic key from interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do a better typing with mongoose schemas, but it seems that the `SchemaTypeOpts` interface has a `[other: string]: any;`, which prevents the vcsode intellisense from helping me.

To solve that i tried the following in the hope that it would identify keys created by the dynamic propriety (since its name is `other`):

```js
const x: Pick<SchemaTypeOpts<any>, Exclude<keyof SchemaTypeOpts<any>, "other">> = {
    bob: "", // expected an error here
    type: String
}
```

but it seems `Exclude` doesn't really do much when the interface has a dynamic property :/

ex:
this works:

```js
interface test2 {
    x?: number,
    y?: string,
    z?: number,
}


const x: Pick<test2, Exclude<keyof test2, "z">> = {
    y: "",
    z: 5, // got error here because z is excluded
    bob: "" //got error here because bob is not in the interface
}
```

this does nothing:

```
interface test2 {
    x?: number,
    y?: string,
    z?: number,
    [other: string]: any;
}


const x: Pick<test2, Exclude<keyof test2, "z">> = {
    y: "",
    z: 5,
    bob: ""
}
```

How can i remove the `[other: string]: any` from the interface without re-declaring the whole thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a wider type from a union type without removing its subtypes in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954558/how-can-i-remove-a-wider-type-from-a-union-type-without-removing-its-subtypes-in)

Comment: The answer in there lets you do `Pick<T,KnownKeys<T>>` to strip off the index signature... or you can do `Pick<T, Exclude<KnownKeys<T>, "keyToRemove">>`.  If you need to add the index signature back into the resulting type you can.

Comment: yes, thank you @jcalz it seems that solved my problem :). I didn't understood the entire piece of code for `KnownKeys` (never saw that `infer` berfore and the `?` at the end confused me a bit too), but everything worked out in the end, now i can declare my schemas with intellisense help and place the documentation on the interfaces (and see it on the schema declaration).