# Why is index signature added by generic argument constraint

Tags: typescript

I dont understand why `{ [k: string]: BooleanType2 | ObjectType2 }` is added to the result of the mapped type. See `Test2`:

What is the correct way to map the type without the index signature is added?

```
type BooleanType1 = {
  type: 'boolean'
  // optional?: boolean
}

type ObjectType1 = {
  properties: { [k: string]: BooleanType1 | ObjectType1 }
}

type Result1<T extends BooleanType1 | ObjectType1> = [T] extends [ObjectType1]
  ? { [Key in keyof T['properties']]: Result1<T['properties'][Key]> }
  : [T] extends [BooleanType1]
  ? boolean
  : never

type Test1 = Result1<{ properties: { p1: { type: 'boolean' } } }> // Type is { p1: boolean }

type BooleanType2 = {
  type: 'boolean'
  optional?: boolean // This causes "[x: string]: never" to be part of Test2
}

type ObjectType2 = {
  properties: { [k: string]: BooleanType2 | ObjectType2 }
}

type Result2<T extends BooleanType2 | ObjectType2> = [T] extends [ObjectType2]
  ? { [Key in keyof T['properties']]: Result2<T['properties'][Key]> }
  : [T] extends [BooleanType2]
  ? boolean
  : never

type Test2 = Result2<{ properties: { p2: { type: 'boolean' } } }> // Type is { [x: string]: never; p2: boolean }
```

Comment: Hi there :). It works as you expect on 3.3 not on 3.4, might be a regression, or a compiler settings thing (tried on, url too long to post)  https://typescript-play.js.org)

Comment: Hi again! :) Interesting fact.

Comment: I think this is a bug, do you want to post it or shall I ?

Comment: I can confirm it works with 3.3.4 and 3.5.0-dev.20190424, but not with 3.4.5. Please do it :)

Comment: Do you know a trick to get rid of the index signature (string | number) from the union of keys (string | number | 'p2')? So I can continue to use 3.4.x until it is fixed or 3.5 is released.

Comment: Have not found a workaround unfortunately :(

Comment: There's a [`KnownKeys<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955852/2887218) type alias you can use to get a list of non-index keys and then you can do `Pick<T, KnownKeys<T>>` to strip off the index signature.  If you apply that to `Test2` it will become just `{p2: boolean}`.