# Typescript keyof one interface extending other interface

Tags: typescript, generics

I have one Basic interface:

```
interface Basic {
  [key: string]: {
    data: string;
  };
}
```

Another interface extending it:

```
interface Another extends Basic {
  'onekey': OneKeyData;
  'secondkey': SeconKeyData;
}
```

My issue with is when use generic `T extends keyof Another` it allows any string keys because of Basic interface. OneKeyData and SecondKeyData they all contain `data` property as in Basic. I would remove `extends Basic` if it wasn't used in other place like this:

```
interface Options<TKey extends keyof Another> {
  field: Another[TKey]['data'];
}
```

What is the best solution in this case? Is it possible to get `keyof` only `Another` interface?

Comment: Your definition of `Options` is currently redundant, since `Another[TKey]['data']` always evaluates to `string` right now. Are there instances in your actual code where this is not the case?

Comment: Furthermore do you really need `Basic`? It might be possible that you can replace you entire data structures with just `Record<string, string>` as indicated by your snippets thus far.

Comment: I don't understand what your use case is, but if you're looking for a way to get the known keys of an interface (that is, without the `string`), [you can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955852/2887218).  If that's what you want I'd be inclined to close this as a duplicate.  Otherwise please explain clearly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is possible to get `keyof` ignoring the index signature using a trick with conditional type inference.

```
type KnownKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;

type KnownKeysOfAnother = KnownKeys<Another> // "oneKey" | "secondKey";
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks!