# How to filter record keys based on their values?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, generic-programming, typescript-generics

I have this record:

```
interface TheRecord extends TheRecordType {
  a: { typeA: 'string' },
  b: { typeB: 123 },
  c: { typeA: 'string' },
}

type TheRecordType = Record<string, TypeA | TypeB>

type TypeA = { typeA: string }
type TypeB = { typeB: number }
```

I want my function to accept only keys who's values are of typeA

```
doStuff('b'); //this should fail

function doStuff(arg: keyof FilteredForTypeA): void {
  ...
}
```

Here's how I try to filter them out

```
type FilteredForTypeA = { [k in keyof TheRecord]: TheRecord[k] extends TypeA ? TheRecord[k] : never }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In TypeScript how to specify only keys of a generic object whose values are strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-specify-only-keys-of-a-generic-object-whose-values-are-stri)

Comment: ugh, except you've got that index signature in there.  You might need to use `KnownKeys` first as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954558/how-can-i-remove-a-wider-type-from-a-union-type-without-removing-its-subtypes-in)

Comment: Thanx @jcalz! Lemme digest..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few things going on here so I'll make an answer since it's not a direct duplicate of the relevant existing questions I found.

When your type has an index signature it's hard to extract just the "known" literal keys of the object if they are subtypes of the index signature.  That is, `keyof {[k: string]: any, foo: any}` is just `string`, and `"foo"` is completely subsumed in that.  You can use a conditional type trick to extract just the known literal keys, as shown in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954558/how-can-i-remove-a-wider-type-from-a-union-type-without-removing-its-subtypes-in):

```
type KnownKeys<T> = Extract<{
    [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never, keyof T>;
```

On the other hand, you want only the keys whose values have a property matching a particular type.  That is doable with a mapped-conditional-lookup, as shown in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-specify-only-keys-of-a-generic-object-whose-values-are-stri):

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

Put those together and you get:

```
type KnownKeysMatching<T, V> = KeysMatching<Pick<T, KnownKeys<T>>, V>
```

And you can verify that it works as I think you intend:

```
function doStuff(arg: KnownKeysMatching<TheRecord, TypeA>): void {
}

doStuff('a'); // okay
doStuff('b'); // error!
doStuff('c'); // okay
doStuff('d'); // error!
```

Note how `arg` cannot be `'b'`, as desired, but it also cannot be `'d'` or any other "unknown" string, even though `TheRecord` has a string index signature.  If you need some other behavior for `'d'`, that could be done, but it seems outside the scope of the question.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#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-nm1JCKPO9Ae1Be95OEA)

Answer (score 2):

Using a slightly modified version of `KnownKeys` to exclude keys whose values also extend never, you end up with this

```
interface TheRecord extends TheRecordType {
  a: { typeA: 'string' },
  b: { typeB: 123 },
  c: { typeA: 'string' },
}

type TheRecordType = Record<string, TypeA | TypeB>
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : T[K] extends never ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;

type TypeA = { typeA: string }
type TypeB = { typeB: number }

function doStuff(arg: KnownKeys<FilteredForTypeA>): void {

}

type FilteredForTypeA = { [k in keyof TheRecord]: TheRecord[k] extends TypeA ? TheRecord[k] : never }

doStuff('b'); // error!
```