# TypeScript - Exhaustive checking for keyof on extensions of indexable types

Tags: typescript, types

I'm having an issue wherein TypeScript is not exhaustively checking types when the `keyof` operator is used on types that extend indexable types.

So, the normal use-case of the keyof operator would be something like a `Pick<T1, T2>` type:

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    alive: boolean;
}

function getPersonInfo<K extends keyof Person>(person: Person, prop: K): Person[K] {
    return person[prop];
}

getPersonInfo({ name: "John", age: 31, alive: true }, "age"); // compiles and returns 31
getPersonInfo({ name: "John", age: 31, alive: true }, "ssn"); // does NOT compile because "ssn" does not match type of "name" | "age" | "alive"
```

But when an indexable type is involved, we no longer get this safety of `keyof` (i.e. a compile-time error telling us that the provided argument is not a key of the type in question). Such as the following:

```js
interface Collection {
    [item: string]: any;
}

interface MyCollection extends Collection {

    thing: string,
    shmoolean: boolean,
    lumber: number

}

function getInfo<C extends Collection, K extends keyof C = keyof C>(collection: C, key: K): C[K] {

    return collection[key];

}

let c: MyCollection = undefined as unknown as MyCollection;

getInfo<MyCollection>(c, "something"); // compiles even though "something" is not a property of MyCollection
```

Now, I think I understand why this is occurring, and I *believe* it is due to the fact that on interfaces that extend indexable types, the 'indexable signature' (if you will) is still present on the type, meaning that the type returned by `keyof` effectively gets widened to `string`.

**So my question** is there any way to prevent this from happening? I need to be able to tag classes with their parent indexable type in order to use them in my type system, so I can't just eliminate the indexable type, but I would also like to be able to exhaustively check the type of provided arguments to `keyof` types and to be given compile-time errors when a non-key is used.

EDIT1: I found a somewhat [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954558/how-can-i-remove-a-wider-type-from-a-union-type-without-removing-its-subtypes-in/51955852#51955852) about removing the index signature from a type by using a wonky type that strips said index signature from a type:

```js
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;
```

So in effect, the new function would be:

```js
function getInfo<C extends Collection, K extends KnownKeys<C> = KnownKeys<C>>(collection: C, key: K): C[K] {

    return collection[key];

}
```

I think this is the direction in which I need to go, but there now I have two problems related to this:

1. The example I just gave above *does not compile*, failing with an error telling me that the type `C` cannot be indexed by the type `KnownKeys<C>`, or what it has narrowed the type down to which is `unknown`... I solved this by using a conditional type like this for the return type:

```js
K extends keyof C ? C[K] : never
```

2. This *still* doesn't seem to be allowing the TypeScript compiler to exhaustively check the type of `keyof`...