# typescript Omit omit all other members if one of the member is { [index: string]: any }

Tags: typescript

```
type a = { a: 1, [index: string]: any , name:string, b?:boolean}
type b = Omit<a,'a'> //b is {[index: string]:any}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=64#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDesBcUCMAaKBtAlgHYAmEAHugM7ABORA5gLroyEhQ6EwC2Eq1dQvRwAjAPyoRAeykAbCKwC+AWABQa0JCgiEUAPLd8wADwwsAchjmAfEA)

type b would be `{[index: string]:any}`, but I expect it to be `{[index: string]: any , name:string, b?:boolean}`

why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and explanation in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954558/how-can-i-remove-a-wider-type-from-a-union-type-without-removing-its-subtypes-in/51955852#51955852)

```
type a = { a: 1, [index: string]: any , name:string, b?:boolean}

declare type _removeIndexSignature<T> = Pick<
        T,
        {
            [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
        } extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U }
            ? U
            : never>

type b = _removeIndexSignature<a> //{ a: 1, name:string, b?:boolean}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDesBcUCMAaKBtAlgHYAmEAHugM7ABORA5gLroyEhQ6EwC2Eq1dQvRwAjAPyoRAeykAbCKwC%20AWABQa0gGNZMGtFCQoAfT3cpANwgBJEuQDK%20el2ABXPQB4AKgD4EUAAr4mgDW7moAkJ5YEUgR4bgA0lBEUMEQIFIAZlCezFACDFDkwBAklFBJYlCEEJY0UOiELtwiEPXFpcTlldW1bQ0VEYpFZCVlyHhGyYSp6Vk5eUSZ-QCqUCqq4eFVK3GNfTRq3monqgbQIn4mEGaWNqRkDk4wrh4w3kA)