# Is it possible to remove a wider type from an literal union in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working with React and Typescript, building a custom input component and I wish to cleanup the allowed values from `type` attribute in the `input` element to prevent unintended used as 'button' and 'hidden'.

The `type` attribute have the type of `HTMLInputTypeAttribute` that's an union type that ends up with `(string & {})`. I don't want the component to receive type values that are not literal described in the union.

Using the `Exclude` utility type results in `never` since all literal types extends from string

I've already looked at other questions like [How can I remove a wider type from a union type without removing its subtypes in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954558/how-can-i-remove-a-wider-type-from-a-union-type-without-removing-its-subtypes-in) but as their intent was not necessarily related to a previously established union, none of the answers met my need

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```js
type Union = 'a' | 'b' | string & {}

type GetLiteral<Type extends string | number, Value> =
    Value extends Type
    ? (Type extends Value
        ? never
        : Value)
    : never

type ObtainLiterals<T> = T extends infer R ? GetLiteral<string, R> : never

// 'a' | 'b'
type Test = ObtainLiterals<Union>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXzB1m)

`GetLiteral` expects a type of union which corresponds to `Type` and a value which corresponds to `Value` generic.

`ObtainLiterals` - distributes a union. It means that each element in the union is called with `GetLiteral` which at the end produces  `'a'|'b'|never`. And `never` is always getting removed from the union.

Comment: I was able to do the trick using `Template Literal Types` but your code looks definitely cleaner. Thank you.
Just in case, my solution was: 
"type ExtractLiteral<T> = T extends `${infer literal}` ? literal : never;"

Comment: @RodrigoNovais nice trick with template literals