# How to omit [key:string]: any from a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Say I have

```
interface A {
  apple?: number;
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface B extends A {
  banana?: number;
}
```

I want a `type C` to extend all from `A` and all from `B` except `[key: string]: any;`. I want a `type D` to inherit all from `B` except all from `A`.

How do I make `C` and `D` in typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove index signature using mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465182/how-to-remove-index-signature-using-mapped-types)

Comment: Accepted answer does not work since TS 4.3. @Derek mind unaccepting it, so I can delete the answer? I think there are now better solutions in linked duplicate posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pick all from `B`, remove `A` index signature:

```
type C = Pick<B, KnownKeys<B>>;
```

Pick all from `B`, exclude all from `A`, remove `A` index signature:

```
type D = Omit<C, KnownKeys<A>>
```

Type `KnownKeys<T>` removes the index signature of `T`, using only the known property keys (credit goes to Mihail Malostanidis and his answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956054/5669456) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955852/5669456)):

```
type KnownKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;
```

How do types `C` and `D` look like?

```
type C = {
    banana?: number | undefined;
    apple?: number | undefined;
}

type D = {
    banana?: number | undefined;
}

const c: C = {
    apple: 1,
    banana: 2,
}

const d: D = {
    banana: 2
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XABwIBsIB+ALmRAFcBbAI2gG4c8BtAawgE8qBnMFFABzALpU4IHqwC+WLKEixEKAELIIAD0ggAJvzSY2uBlPOVq9JlDkKwPAigDSIAPYB3EM978APAAqAHzIALzGeMjszsigyNw8bjDIARLIgsIgIpo6EPqGMWTUEABu0MhUtIzl2roGyIXFZVAVDViyOXWGGFEA+rEg8bxJKWmgMOUAqsgdRdOVpSwKAPTLnXl6+MTEyDBQbnRGUptw27v7hxraSARgUQkCQqJpUjIAdMhYDk7IAMJhyAACsAEJw-GoADQNdxeHw8fxqIJBVhYVbrfRbHZ7A7IK5aG53U5Yi5oN5fRwoAAiAIA8nRgGA-L8oa5PN5fH5UEiFAg3CBBMgEFR-uFsJFCCQIFQAIwQkzIMwgcxUABMcvkWF5-Lueio1NF8sVyuQKvaQA)

Comment: How do I do a generic typing that can pass any `A`, `B` to get a `D`? I want to do something like `type OwnKeysOnly<T, U> = Omit<Pick<T, KnownKeys<T>>, KnownKeys<U>>;`, but I get a `TS2344: Type 'KnownKeys<T>' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof T'.` error and a `TS2344: Type 'KnownKeys<U>' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.` error.

Comment: You could implement `D` like this: `type D<A, B extends Record<any, any>> = Pick<B, Exclude<KnownKeys<B>, KnownKeys<A>>>`. With your interfaces `A` and `B` you can create a new type: `type Concrete = D<A, B>`.

Comment: Future readers: the solution is deprecated since 4.3.1-rc, there is an alternative since 4.1. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955852/6529098

Comment: @AmauryLiet thanks! I'll mark this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
type NoStringIndex<T> = { [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : K]: T[K] };

interface A {
  apple?: number;
  [key: string]: any;
}

type A2 = NoStringIndex<A>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do that in the way you think (exclude `[key: string]: any;`) in sense that to exclude a key you have to use the key or its value type.

Instead you can pick the properties you want:

```js
type C = Pick<B, 'apple' | 'banana'>;
```