# Question about how Omit built-in utility type work

Tags: typescript

The code below is a simplified version of the problematic code.
While appropriate type inference occurred in type O, no type inference was made for types Y and U.

```
type Obj = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

type DoesObjWorkOnlyForSubsequence<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K>;

type Something = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c?: string;
  d?: string;
};

type O = DoesObjWorkOnlyForSubsequence<Something, 'c'> & Obj;

const check: O = {
  // proper inference
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  d: 'd',
};

interface Y extends Omit<O, 'c'> {}

const check2: Y = {
  // can't infer anything here.
};

type U = Omit<O, 'b'>;

const check3: U = {
  // can't infer anything here.
};
```

Is this issue related to `Omit` or `Obj`? If so, why is type inference possible in type O?

I would like to know the exact reason why it works this way.

Comment: What "inference" are you talking about? You're not doing anything where something would be *inferred* at all. Maybe you're just using the wrong terminology? What specifically do you mean? Use different words.

Comment: Presumably you're asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58242898/2887218) and the answer is there as well as [ms/TS#42436](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42436). Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz You are totally right. I was meant to ask why the explicit members are dropped even though they are not specified by Omit utility. Your answer adressed my question. Thank you :D