# How to combine index types with intersection types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type which accepts residual properties as follows:

```js
export type Base = {
  numberProperty: number;
  booleanProperty: boolean;
};

export type Residual = {
  [key: string]: string;
};

export type Complete = Base & Residual;

const abc: Complete = {
  numberProperty: 1234,
  booleanProperty: true,
  residualProperty: 'abc',
};
```

In other words, I want to make sure `numberProperty` and `booleanProperty` are always of `number` and `boolean` type respectively, but any other property should be `string`. However, when compiling this (3.9.2), I get the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ numberProperty: number; booleanProperty: true; residualProperty: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Complete'.
  Type '{ numberProperty: number; booleanProperty: true; residualProperty: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Residual'.
    Property 'numberProperty' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

13 const abc: Complete = {
         ~~~


Found 1 error.
```

I've found similar questions and documentation that addresses similar issues, but I have yet to find a conclusive answer of how to do this.

Comment: Your `Residual` makes any definition in base completely useless, as the `numberProperty` and `booleanProperty` are also keys for an object, maybe you could find a way to exclude those keys from the `Residual` definition? Though if you could maybe simply move where the other properties are defined on the object :)

Comment: Does this one help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216298/how-to-omit-keystring-any-from-a-type-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Residual` has a conflict with keys `numberProperty` and `booleanProperty` from `Base`, because they aren't string.

To fix it you need to change `Residual` to say that everything except `Base` is string. After that `Residual` respects `Base` and they can be combined together.

```js
export type Base = {
  numberProperty: number;
  booleanProperty: boolean;
};

export type Residual = {
  [K in keyof any]: K extends keyof Base ? never : string;
};

export type Complete = Base | Residual;

const abc: Complete = {
  numberProperty: 1234,
  booleanProperty: true,
  residualProperty: 'abc',
};
```

If you can't change `Residual`, then you should reconsider your code to avoid their union because it has a conflict and won't be valid.

```js
const val1: Residual = {
  numberProperty: 'string', // valid, positive
};
const val2: Base = {
  numberProperty: 'string', // invalid, negative
};
const val3: Residual | Base = {
  numberProperty: 'string', // positive & negative = negative.
};
```

---

for a deep type respect we have to omit `string` and always operate with defined keys. Usually people have 2 options - specify all keys or to use a validation function.

```js
export type Base = {
  numberProperty: number;
  booleanProperty: boolean;
};

export type Residual<KEYS extends keyof any = keyof any> = {
  [K in KEYS]: string;
};

export type Complete<K extends keyof any> = Base & Residual<Exclude<K, keyof Base>>;

const abc: Complete<'residualProperty'> = {
  numberProperty: 1234,
  booleanProperty: true,
  residualProperty: 'abc',
};

const booleanVariable: boolean = abc.booleanProperty;


const validateComplete = <T extends Complete<K>, K extends keyof T>(value: T): Complete<K> => value;

const abc2 = validateComplete({
  numberProperty: 1234,
  booleanProperty: true,
  residualProperty: 'abc',
});

const booleanVariable2: boolean = abc2.booleanProperty;
const stringVariable2: string = abc2.residualProperty;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, the proposed answer introduces a side-effect of making all properties optionally string. Adding the following to the proposed change triggers another error:

```
const booleanFunc = (bool: boolean) => {
  return bool;
}

const x = booleanFunc(abc.booleanProperty);
```

Error:

```
Argument of type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: have you removed question mark after `[K in keyof any]`? I think it was the latest change yesterday.

Comment: and `[key: string]: string` does exactly that - it says all properties are strings. All custom fields should be defined in `Base` otherwise you should remove `Residual` because its signature forces everything to be strings.

Comment: Yes, I do believe I've copied it over correctly. I'm ok with this, although it would be great to somehow keep the types defined in `Base` unaffected by `Residual` when expecting an object of `Complete` type. Perhaps this will be added in a future version of TypeScript.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, then `never` can help here, I've updated the answer. Now `Residual` doesn't have keys from `Base` at all.

Comment: I tried with the updated code, but `const booleanVariable: boolean = abc.booleanProperty;` still complains `Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Now I see what you mean, yeah TS is tough time to time.

Comment: I added to the answer one more option, it's not the best one, but it's the only way I know.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Glad to hear! Happy coding!