# How to explain the meaning of KnownKeys type in IDB?

Tags: typescript

```
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K;
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U }
  ? U
  : never;
```

I feel confused with this type. I cannot understand it. It seams filter all string literal props as an union type. Since

```
declare let a: KnownKeys<{ test: 34, 23: 'test' }>
a = 'test' // Done.
// a = 23 Error.
// a = '23' Error.
```

How does it achieves this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strong guess is that purpose of `KnownKeys` is to get all explicit or "known" keys from a hybrid type with both hard-coded properties *and* index signature (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465182/typescript-remove-index-signature-using-mapped-types) for more info and type credit).

`KnownKeys` has no effect on a type without index signature:

```
type T11 = KnownKeys<{ test: 34, 23: 'test'}> // "test" | 23
type T12 = keyof { test: 34, 23: 'test'} // same as above
```

But with a hybrid type, there is a difference:

```
type T21 = KnownKeys<{ [K: string]: number, foo: number }> // here we can extract "foo" 
type T22 = keyof { [K: string]: number, foo: number } // string | number, this is not so useful...
```

It works, because a mapped type returns both the index signature and explicit  properties:

```
type T3 = {[K in keyof { [K: string]: number, foo: number }]: number}
// { [x: string]: number; foo: number; } returns signature and "foo" property
```

So we can assign a `never` value to the signature part `[x: string]: number` with the type expression `string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K`. And just filter out all properties with `never` value by `extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;`.
[Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=6&pln=13&pc=18#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gdgewO5xhEBnAPAFQHxQC8UA3gLABQU1UA2jFAJZxQDW6CAZlDgLoBcUDMABOzAOZQIAD2AQ4AEwywoAfihwIANwgioguAFcAtgCNdU2fKUr1mnXsEwA3JQC%20luYuUk6AfSYWdhAuHgFAzgsAVSg3Sho1KCj4mgNtXVcKSlBIHgBGPKJYRBQ0TCxfOWFBAGYAFgAaKAAmGsEAcirgdrcCAHo%20qAAiLqGoAB8WmuzwaBw85qLg0MqIaqh6ptaOrp6oAaEAQ2NoQ%20VD0wQdShncnGbC4nhkVHRsX3pBYTE4cXCjMy6JqcBAIAwmcx6Xr7QZDEEIIa3ObNRbEZbcD4wL6iCT-CFAqDw8GAqEwoQ434TDT4kQ3Cg5OY1IokeiBNgcDF0LHkn5-YmQ4Gg-kWNx4klxCgHD7SbG8sWQ5yEoXUkmKiWUBQQADGABtDiJoDqIMAoIdBPNCgcRmtgGNJq1KIcitbhEMmk7iK0yUgECJWBg6ZrdfrDcaoKYnCVXuUWdzvrjhSJBWCVZDoQd4ZRTM74YishQgA)

Comment: So, the index signature is also regarded as a 'prop'. Disable this prop does not affect other literal prop declaration.

Comment: yeah kinda, if you want to see it this way. And instead of "disabling" the signature, I would rather consider it as creating a new type from a hybrid type. In the hybrid type, props have to conform to the signature as usual.

Comment: A new type based on the current type. Got it.