# How to match a declared conditional infer type with another similar conditional infer type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, indexeddb, typescript-generics

Continue from [the previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59500317/how-to-explain-the-meaning-of-knownkeys-type-in-idb). I am now defining an API interface based on IDB. An conditional infer type conflicts with the `KnownKeys` type, which stops me from integrating declaration of IDB.
Here is [the details](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhhA9gBwJYFMAm0BmAnRAW2gEkARAIQDpoBlVQ5AG1Rw0yqlmCgBcBPZOmgBpAHaIA7mJHp+AZwA8AFQB80ALzQA3l2gBtEdFRjoAazmIc0ZQF0AXNHm88JgObR0AD17oxmeVFoAH5oMXQAN3Q8aEcxAFdCACNozx8-AKDQ8KiYxxEAbigAXzTff0DtAwB9Y1MLfisbBzqcVIBVaGK9UPa9OMjoosg+QWFKWgBjAAt0QgBDTR09fQbHZ1cxNxb5sX4SqFGhOl5EPHQAOXnCdCVKZTHA73LMiZm5xYAfaHixMwlpOotPdHmUMoE3rMFiFRACZHI7hQHkJ5Op1i53MMoKAIDA4ABZfg-XioFgk25cEA8SAmXx4HDzSbCEhiCKIMzuRR6KZQxbPcHQSEfJa7fgAGm5p3OYIqJzOl2ut0UPI+QOgor06l0MGgwGAgvQbHC0AWyCEMQ28UmvHi504OoAFJhDY5tM55Y5aFL0MUAJSxdV7A6QPXQdokpjQU6tVICY74Igm+Zm6JHcYUL3ylltPDK94LMU2NX6OwyzL6J0unROb2OEw5uhdf0adSi2w9Rv82WZ85XG5KFULVR6aAw2gjgM5VM6ga5LEh-VkQ0mYTIeZ4RV0mt4K0285QWnRBlM6AAQTQXJ1feEWl+-ykYglOsHfPSsqF0K0oqfo57wi7mR-teA75vMaoajqWp6GIiqONewyju65zBJ63rDN0IwLgaRrCPI0QRKgJ6HvSjLoDQJDyPI8S3NAsx2geYh0sewgAAoEARzq5tyoFlhCGY8V+ew-tA+LJuavHQAASugkxnJgigbO4hYsmyHJbHmvKqGq2gYaOUE6jiI5wMiwgAOR-qZ0CYIgNESLwTjzCS8g4ESvCzNAsliBs8y0tA5nesBGmqqZ9qjrANhjH5Ezetm0RBQWIlidE+jXrYqiWaggR2eqlGoG4MFJEwwjRnGZlAYqIGaSFDoAEwAMwACwNb6RnUqO5xuJldKXmF0DXhJDRNKJKZ4MJv7ehJ0VZmIObxfMhbDeaKWKmlE6qA6yaoI456oIo16Fi+B3eqovqOBBegmKp6A7YoO0DZY1iLdE60Tm5mWOGxiAcXFh2JSNqhjWEFVrky21oHop2kKy7I-aBC1JXg+g7Wl6GHDSjFHqRUNXbmL6TfxvKFsoEkqey7j6aOl0ww6kOfYQmXoIo0l7mIJkqFpJRAA).

```
interface Provider<
  Schema extends DBSchema = any,
  Mapper extends Record<string, Invoking<Schema>> = {}
  > {
  /**
   * Type 'Store' does not satisfy the constraint 'StoreNames<Schema>'.
   * Type 'DBStoreInfer<Schema, Mapper[Name]>' is not assignable to type 'StoreNames<Schema>'.(2344)
   */
  register<
    Name extends keyof Mapper,
    Store extends DBStoreInfer<Schema, Mapper[Name]>
  >(api: Api<Name, Schema, Store>): any // Error.
}
```

I dont know how to match the requirement of `StoreNames<Schema>`(implemented by `KnownKeys`). Even using `S extends StoreNames<Schema>` in `DBStoreInfer` can not resolve it.
Currently, I walk around by using the IDB type directly

```
...
  register<
    Name extends keyof Mapper,
    Store extends StoreNames<Schema>
  >(api: Api<Name, Schema, Store>): any // Good. But lost type validation in other class using Mapper.
...
```

Any way to fix it? Or any idea to rework the design?

#### Update:

I come up with a use case. It is built on a [base interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=8&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiAhAssGALCAEzgF44ByAc13LgB8KBDQw2h8sAVxjYsOAA2uYL3IBjIYyjkAsACh5oSLDgBLAHYxgUAGaMxqTAEEwqgMqrK6xjE5RgAHjgB6Z3ABi0ALY35cOGYw0KhknOoA1uoQAO7qADR+cDj4RHCgWuqEAM7o2LgExGSM6ogJcv4AkpmgwDmhEVGxZf4AipzaiGkgGdlwAErAYtCEDlkwUBqUcXDFiAB8pDMlzeg2jF09OQNDUCNjE+pTS-OLsysDWZDqWSFwYZEx6gvpwJk5JuaW1rb2DhdXNwWAG9EmNggB+ABcASC9gA3C5nAAVADyaBR0KwjHCqDAUAgYDg9gAjpxVPZCABCRJefJEKFJOmEBGuVHozHY3H4wkkskU6nlNTVEC1BlVfgirJwxKkjoMtodaWCwhrBloNZKgC+8nkzgAVHq-Hq4EjkKgIDo4EYAAoVOD8HQaVQwVQQdQAOiNzkU4Gg8A0Wl0+kMGCqADcIOFJqaUE5XB5vL5BWYxHhgD4Nq9epgU2mM0VlolAsFM28YcEAHKMWlZBy59OMBYF0qJZIFUvZvIpQrHFbimo5F5loxQKCMRAOfsgKs1uuphvTYv2OZN3uJBVQTpD3rbYajcaTaazVdnRLqmDrbdbQZ7-aH44nwuC-5um6Le6NJ5wEGCgAUDuhIE4DBexoSXYAEQ0CVamhKdagRWlu0xJkEVlTdoQ3Up7TWaFz3WTUAEpoRfa4IPkbUFDkJQ-QQM1cg+GNHERBMoB8GAi3nDMr1yet8zXQUZ1uD9HhWcCOxycDBNrXjG1OJ9-DbVJuMwRSe1PQU4LqfjWnaTdxP6G9dn3A4jmPOSW0FPD9N3Iy70OI8SkfCz-BIt96geWJVw+KodAgBxBIWAAyejTAsKwbDsRxwOmVTpk06ZMOmPDplc4A5h1OR9UNcpjQuCABDDbQcl8qArVMLEwEYz0cu9KjfRUJAUFyVSfO0BwkS80xw0jSZWqgdrnm6LMcgAbSAxCCmhDQdG0JI4E1BzEAAXTgcE5uUrt2zWrA4GhdRgEK0q9oO7QfWUeBGpDcC+rnPNGGmDrFm89QIyjQ4bse7ixuA2FgCm9QZtKsx5sWla1uB7jJOrWpbobBZwd2uB9sOxHke0JVqIaujME0m6ZIezrVG6t7KA+wbNjgb6QL+oVAYCaYoIHaERzHCdptmioFgW44wYCfSodnGT4bgO1uKnKTYZ8RdhbtY6Ubl2aFagDH6ou7GMEwsmnq6l6evegG2s+oay2+tDEH+umWhBnnVrgK3uJsvYD3sh9batpXUZOqAzpoy7cjwrWyGe17eoN-qjYp76VQvC3ZrQa3Zl5+OHcMp2TMW4X449pWMsx-1NG0PQDFyYntBRMAXVffTg8jMuK9da5vwyiifZUANC+DEvdZxKBGMly9jc7fGTX0nHu+jM1yeGsqie77Q+8en9-A0V7gF-RJ-HwVQslw0M597s1+4JlZ-AJSvrjVPfV6gcvz6yRIiLga18S8bfHAGH51AXlclUSRnJUnMKUee9oJZDxpxe6JoVzr0FJvPA29d6lwPrGYeHUT5CglIJWCwoH6IP3n3VBcxf6CjNjA-wcCEFd2vgQiBx8N5wDNrvTWYcBq4KobXZBUVaFQOIf4aOjAyHkK3jvdhPcaF3TobA7CMd-ZrDJmwse1DD6EK1LnVWtEmqYGfhAMMqh+A33rq+fuwCZL0DuA0R474LGeUWEve0AAjKSYBgzQjspQJU-hDpZAbntTgXh7Ho3InAYK5dXiYAAMKMAEAIex+hwjSQgelSiechSBiLiGbRuj9F92Yp4ViSZ-CmI2qY5sKwKooFKinHYad7yKL1pQcRcNVxAk1FPYcphMl6Pnofcp2hgSJCyhvXKtRcBwCGADSwcALRjLsPYTQcA8Q6K6VAaq5DjQAAFnFji8FMwx1whm1X8OMx0lBBEUJEVo-EWTukoO4b0qAcx0FnwbiI60UgXRRIcJcpZ+jb4vP7iuBRGBOnZOUXcxgYAKlEIyv4QZsDhmUG3oGJGwBohWltHAEqMzRyvHgIs65KyhlwE2VIasMxTDortA6VZ-g9SHKJMARFYxtAfDjG4PJbF6GCX0jiRA0z7noPjGJYpv1wESKSBCipI1BJLUefQ4Vg8JK-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-wj9tGvxuH8JzlboWUSOW6faYgYC-mU98glV6YoibmL5l+b9JxaLwrEgLQskmaiAA)(developing)

```
// Model
type Entity = {
  id: string,
  code: string,
  data: number
}

// Somewhere in the common module.
declare const provider: DBProviderType<{
  'db-store': {
    key: string,
    value: Entity,
    indexes: {
      'db-compound-index': [string, number],
      'db-code-index': string
    }
  }
}, {
  testApi: (def: {
      store: 'db-store',
      method: 'get'
      indexes: ['code'],
      query: Entity
    }
  ) => Entity
}>

// Somewhere during app init. The Mapper type may be a subset.
// Arguments follow the structure of Mapper and Schema
provider.registerApi({
  name: 'testApi',
  store: 'db-store',
  method: 'get',
  indexes: 'db-compound-index'
})

// Somewhere in business logic
provider.invokeApi('testApi')
  .indexes('db-code-index')
  .query({
    code: 'test-code',
    data: 1001
  })
  .invoke()
```

#### Update 2

[Another definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=4&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwLACg5wIJmASQHYBmEANKulrngG4QDWAplAPJgzAR4DOpam2%20NBlAAqATzD0e5ftTrA8Ac3wFGUvpUHyFYiWooAFKBCrAAJox2Sy6gEr1OkLvWWr1AZWAK8AQxgBXKHpUAF84AiMQOAByADoYgHo4%20PkYRgJvAGN6KNRQSFhEOCYqRgB3KGBUuFDwiEiogAEADwyoEHi-NgAbThyUVHom-PgYcXo4AAkYGDAAWXoYAAsIUzgAXmiFBai4AB9oyE4YHf2osE6T6PMuhezUAaHoeBS0zPGpmYoPL18A%20gAeODxeJwABi0BAvmsAFE8KZICk4INUnDOHAjhVFOs4N48KI1PMliskU0UaY0R85gtlqsNrj8dYAIp%20RiiElktF2DLQUz-DFaYg4vEAPmx9LU%20m8UG8IDRyPoqLgXJ5fJgmIUgvporpeLUdgcHE44w2fjwtDwEFKeFF8sVX08Pn8gX%20%20scRtFyF4CvhEBSAH4AFxwWE%20lIAbiBIOETAAIkwg7NvAw4GAjGA4IEAI5%20YCBUwAQmsIGpK0DcEJNIjwLg0bjCaT41TEHTWZzecLvGzrLLzNZYesYClMs4Zcl0tl-ZQwXuKHiACo52Q5zWxnAIARMPocHBzAR5JV2HgYkv4g9hnAXlB0llJtMwAI5IpLP8YXCEXh4Lbyei1VoxbrrArYkvwpO8gNpIUGV4XsoDZEClXobkoF5flFE1EV-yg9Ax2HdlvU5RCVVQjVIO1SC9XsN1jTgU1zUta08LtGRNCfMYXUow16A9awAApdyDBAkTfX0PyDEN3xgQViyJUwExLUwIy7WCgxg0QI0HcdOCDHDZWqABKINXU4ydp36WcFyXBDOAgLoSigNEiCgdREzASxjzQOdTxQQZz1GCRb0%20bBn2sAA5GVqNoi0rTUcSRM-Ul8J-dVMIJeTGO-SlwJSpkWVg9KCKQlDfzQ0jst4HS5QSxVlWQ1V1XQ0QyPFawjKcbFIvosiKGUCB-jC4tRQAMgCsB7R%20J0AVilJBXAwVVMFCrBVa90zyeOA-PeO8xsdP4XCgf5hDIgBtYQAF18rgI6%20PoAgg3kFQnIAVT09ZRXuxglXOv0Ru235nUpKaPz2g7hUFTL5OBw6wbvVTIdBkaKrhpbRSDPB6Ds1aCg2kbAZgOHsW62RaC0fH4KOwTvQku7CA%206Fqgar7gwu4i4G%20unUfRj6OYx7zHix1dwZk-GNkJlilBp-bDou8m4GkmlqYe8t6cgxnZguwWaVZpXua5uA0Z5ny1uxylYYlkGCeYx9xYe82ycEpTRAVj7GWV%20lGZd%20CaqK%20rSu%20l2dacgPMZGAW70Rs2pZFy3icUUmqu-GWNOHJ2nP0V28UZtPPcI2riIa0VvrTgO4CDszDf5-zKQMIwACtELYDhnwodW7wfGPtDGMj-hjGAIBbwLgG%20HbAmxKvsCHv7nDNihhWFHjrAIPAg3n3h0G8bAgzHweHUn4GZ7UdBuUIXMQGXwJOD8LoYDLJgQEqbve8FKJz6oqJhRetZRRoMxrA-r-fVWPsHifFe5Bh7hAI6z8OJOCiKdP%20CEnR4Cbtgd%20qB4Hf1MDOcuzwPyvBvJSNujAWANy4BdUWdAiGsEPGiT0IQsF8xwakK8bwRqEJEGxYQ-d7xEy0JYG08c0TkKEM%20KWnp0DyEEPQHiSxgBaVYUTCwHD4bNhISOTercFHMCoYaAycBDB1FkQCOwiCRGin2HgS%20XRhSTgHEOWU0jFiyPUTMNhpjBRJ1lM4sA4cbaHV0QQzRpibGdlyqIBxTj5GSPYRIEGgoHZeNNr49%20XjXFKJMvQ88l5rybRmPokw5gtGqMQNYRYd4JgQCOEGYik50CLHoN4ApaiEKFTqgKJKf5zF%20BAAAI0YNYuhZcGEXlwcw-BYcjD5MUTElyEgnLZxaXnSJVs%20HYgQMEfhHJ1B5LMFMgEMy%20nFN4PORcq9lz6gWHAI%20e4FBrg3BkAIgQPwpgmTsqA7l0BwGXA0Dxa5tFcGsJ8ry1grmeHCXIyk2yCnPn2VAZRfy5FjjYN4Lo-wIUvIKcQ6hySEbot2f8GF-SzLoGOQCs59AFCyKYXregpRNzbkcpch5Cp4BNkmW80lcBvl2JxNgOlO4brvPQJ5awgQKVHEYBQF8q84D9XGPBBgoh1zlnXrMg%20wZhKInggDDVQMzYwqOrK06oMAXljSlqsCEM9UqsYAa8KRq1WqS4Ykxg%20LrVQFtcWe1JqKpcJ8S6-VhrjXSuWnKgRthoFGmBgGu1s8V4fPWo48F4zjCvOhW6oN8b17AC8RQZ8srBS4xmvJOaoSFp2O4FZKiwpf4CRNWqXEnBHKnx%20tgfRdcMgkLTWAWZHr6BGusKZawJLTlwDcDAKU8BvDrVXJwbwKg%20USKtoKz5nKfk%20GLA4Fh67xhKowFuflBBl3Ct4Iuhgkrm7yvoIqjcBKeLbs3VkIMFB-EaKiV2ntFAjXBOJRZEdABhQIvhxjSlpa2ewMAj2ru5Vm0lXlD6AdSHYLsRwpXxtlRdBVSqYVqtxlw3GUa3W9q9dKrK5qZjgQI92m1gaHWhKdaEyjPaaPevLb68tjHqMxrVSGsh2AQ0cfdYGuedbE1eMhXiglaqs1BmKGUCoqRUVbSCmxfN6rQwfiLTJEtrIy2aSWhGrigpBLbrLCzdZNa9EREMexA0bVOldCseklAQA) for Jsonp/Ajax. For design discussion.

Comment: You went hard here :D

Comment: @MaciejSikora I try my best.

Comment: Can you write what you want to achieve in terms of use case? I feel its overcomplicated

Comment: @MaciejSikora Yes I also feel it overcomplicated. I update a use case. What I want is built a type-safed DB module. When using it, define a subset mapper as API type for end user.

Comment: have you considered just using templated functions and being done with it? in other words, typify at a higher api layer rather than trying to get idb itself typed, and do all data access via the proxy layer where functions are templated

Comment: @Josh I like template function. What I dont know is how to make the type check work for proxy layer when the inner adapter changed. I update another interface for Jsonp/fetch. I am trying to simplify it.