# Why I can't use Omit on AsyncProps of react-select?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I've been trying to wrap a component `SelectSearchResult` around `AsyncSelect` from `react-select`. I'd like that the props of my custom component to be almost the same of `AsyncSelect` with some exceptions.

```js
import AsyncSelect, { Props as AsyncSelectProps } from "react-select/async";

// works, but Props allows all properties
type Props = AsyncSelectProps<{ label: string; value: string }>;

const SelectSearchResult = (props: Props) => {
    return <AsyncSelect {...props} />;
};
```

I assumed I just needed to omit the keys I didn't want.

```
type Props = Omit<AsyncSelectProps<{ label: string; value: string }>, "loadOptions">;
```

However, when I inspect `Props`, it has now the following format and I am clueless of why is it taking this shape from.

```
type Props = {
  [x: string]: any;
  [x: number]: any;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found out that the problem actually lies on the way `AsyncProps` is defined, because in its body an index signature is found which makes `Exclude` or `Omit` not work properly.

To illustrate the problem:

```
// This type accepts the known keys `a` and `b` as strings and anything 
// else with unknown keys
type MyType = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    [key: string]: any; // index signature
};

type MyTypeWithoutA = Omit<MyType, "a">;

// I expected the object below to complain for the fact, that "b" is not defined
// but it doesn't happen
const obj: MyTypeWithoutA = {};
```

The solution I've found was to first get to create a derived type of `MyType` without the index signature and create an alternative version of `Omit`

```
type KnownKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;

// K is the union of keys I want to omit from the known keys of T
type OmitKnownKeys<T, K extends string> = Omit<Pick<T, KnownKeys<T>>, K>;
```

Rewriting the code to

```
type MyTypeWithoutA = OmitKnownKeys<MyType, "a">;

const obj: MyTypeWithoutA = {}; // error, b is not defined (what I wanted)
```

**Important**: this solution works for my specific case, but it actually drops the index signature from your type, making it less flexible, in other words you can't pass any arguments that'll match the index signature. Check [this version](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31153#issuecomment-487872268) if you want to keep your index signature.

Sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956054/1657165), [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25987#issuecomment-408339599)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `never` type and `&` operator. e.g.: `type Props =AsyncSelectProps<{ label: string; value: string }> & {loadOptions: never };`

When someone will try to call `Props.loadOptions` it will returns `never` and never is not assignable to any types, so it will raise error in next usage.