# Remove TypeScript Indexable Type from Interface

Tags: typescript

I'm working with angular-gridster2, which has an interface, GridsterConfig:

```
export interface GridsterConfig {
    fixedColWidth?: number;
    fixedRowHeight?: number;
...
    [propName: string]: any;
}
```

The problem is, the propName allows any property to be added or referenced, allowing for typos to be ignored by the compiler.  This compiles just fine:

```
let foo: GridsterConfig = {};
foo.doesnotexist = "OOPS";
```

I know that I can create a new interface with Pick:

```
type MyGridsterConfig1 = Pick<GridsterConfig, 'fixedColWidth' | 'fixedRowHeight'>;
let mgc1: MyGridsterConfig1 = {};
mgc1.doesnotexist = 100;  // <-- compiler error
```

And can use Omit on explicit properties, but I haven't found a way to effectively do:

```
Omit<GridsterConfig, '[propName: string]'>.
```

The only thing I've found so far is to Pick all the properties (there's a number of them).
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: remove index signature using mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465182/typescript-remove-index-signature-using-mapped-types)

Comment: @bugs: Yes, that's what I was looking for. There's no way I'd ever have come up with that (though I wonder how I missed it in my search).

Comment: @bugs: Do you want to add that as an answer?