# How can I remove arbitrary keys when creating a type from an existing type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type defined as:

```js
type ExistingType = {
  [key: string]: any;
  name: string;
  mobile?: string;
}
```

Now I want to create a type from this without the arbitrary keys like this:

```js
type DerivedType = {
  name: string;
  mobile?: string;
}
```

Does there exist a less manual way of doing this without picking up the keys using `Pick` utility type?

I used `Pick` utility type to achieve this in the following way:

```js
type DerivedType = Pick<ExistingType, 'name' | 'mobile'>
```

It works but it is very verbose, and if there are many keys in the original type then it becomes very tedious and unclean.

Comment: **All:** The goal here is to remove **the index signature**, so it's not just a case of "use `Omit`." :-)

Comment: ... **but** it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465182/how-to-remove-index-signature-using-mapped-types