# Typescript interface for possibly-recursive object with catch-all props

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define an optionally-recursive structure in typescript, like this:

```
interface SceneObject {
  name: string
  type: string
  children?: SceneObject[]
  [k: string]: object|string|Array<number>
}
```

But ts complains about my `children` object, saying:`Property 'children' of type 'SceneObject[] | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'string | object | number[]'`

It seems to be confused between `children` and the `k` catchall at the end. How would I capture this concept of an object that *may* have a `children` prop, and if it does, it must be a `SceneObject[]`?

Note: if I make `children` non-optional, it compiles OK. Maybe what I need is some way to indicate that the catchall clause must not be "children"?

**Edit: here's a worked-out solution:**

```
interface SceneObjectCore {
  name: string
  type: string
  children?: SceneObject[]
}

type SceneObject = SceneObjectCore & {
  [k: string]: object|string|Array<number>
}

let a: SceneObject = {
  name: "myname",
  type: "mytype",
  otherProp: [123],
  children: [{
    name: "name2",
    type: "child"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar question here: [How do I exclude an index signature from a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297731/how-do-i-exclude-an-index-signature-from-a-type)

Along with the accepted answer there, I would add that you can define your "catchall" to include `undefined` which would match your definition for `children`:

`[k: string]: object | string| Array<number>| undefined`

Comment: Thanks -- I went with the answer in the question you linked, using an interface and a type that extends it. Added a worked-out example above.